# Why do my app buttons mixed and change their location?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm just new to Android app. I designed a calculator. Buttons and other items on different phones go somewhere else.
They mix and change their place.
For example, on the Galaxy A7, they're right. But the buttons on the Galaxy S7 and S3 change.
I've read a lot of questions, but I could not solve the problem.
An example of the my xml code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
            android:text="Cos"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/showNumbers"
            android:layout_width="344dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
            android:text="7" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
            android:text="8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="101dp"

            android:layout_marginLeft="174dp"

            android:text="9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/zarb"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="256dp"
            android:text="×" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tagsim"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="256dp"

            android:text="÷" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sum"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="256dp"

            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mines"
            android:layout_width="109dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="256dp"

            android:text="-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"

            android:text="" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="149dp"
            android:text="4" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b8"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:text="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b9"
            android:layout_marginLeft="174dp"
            android:text="6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="174dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b6"
            android:text="3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
            android:text="0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bsm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
            android:text="+/-" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bm"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="174dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/b3"
            android:text="." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clean"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="172dp"
            android:text="C" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/result"
            android:layout_width="331dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mosavy"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="295dp"
            android:text="=" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pro"
            android:layout_width="364dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="345dp"
            android:text="ماشین حساب پیشرفته" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
            android:text="Sin"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/t2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="94dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ctan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
            android:text="Ctan"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="182dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="125dp"
            android:text="Tan"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </Rela[۵][1]tiveLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

It is link of my app photo on galaxy s7  http://uupload.ir/files/sova_photo_in_galaxy_s7.jpg an it is on a7 http://uupload.ir/files/86cm_photo_on_galaxy_a7.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, learn how to use `ConstraintLayout` and use it, it's really helpful;

Anyway, if you don't want to use it, put the `RelativeLayout` as main tag and delete the `ConstraintLayout`, it useless and expensive having one layout that contains just another layout.

Then, Android dimensions are really different from device to device, and so also the screen dpi, so, it's correct to use `dp`, but in most case it doesn't solve the problem.

Try to add this line in your `build.gradle` (Module: app) in `dependencies`:

```
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
```

And then express your dimension in xml file with:

```
"@dimen/_[number]sdp"
```

For example, your "showNumbers" EditText will become so:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/showNumbers"
        android:layout_width="344dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_58sdp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
```

It won't be precise to the millimeter, but it's more precise that using just `dp`

**Important:** Don't forget to "sync now" the gradle when you add lines in `.gradle` files

Comment: Thanks for your guidance
I will try to use this later on.
But my problem was not resolved.

Comment: It is link of my app photo on galaxy s7  http://uupload.ir/files/sova_photo_in_galaxy_s7.jpg an it is on a7 http://uupload.ir/files/86cm_photo_on_galaxy_a7.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Without any images, to show what's the actual problem, I can only give you my best guess.

Most likely, your issue is due to you using hardcoding exact values of width and margins.

An example of what I mean:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mosavy"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
```

You're giving the exact dp value for what you want for width and margins.

This is okay if you're coding for only one specific device, but Android is a platform used across a great deal of devices with many different devices having different screen resolutions.

Therefore, 170dp might look good on one device, but it'll appear too large on another device or it might appear too small on another device.

Because of that, Android uses Dimensional Resources to combat this problem.

You should notice a `dimens.xml` file in the `values` folder of your App project.

Inside this file, you can create something like:

```
<dimen name="mosavy_height">170dp</dimen>
```

Then you can replace height in the mosavy button with:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/mosavy"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/mosavy_height"
```

By making this change, you're telling the system to plug in 170dp into the width.

But don't think we're just taking extra steps to accomplish the same task. The real purpose of this is because you can declare the same `mosavy_height` in a `dimens.xml` file of another `values` folder in your app.

For example, you can create another folder named `values-xxxhdpi`, then put in a `dimens.xml` file in there with the line:

```
<dimen name="mosavy_height">190dp</dimen>
```

So now, your layout file will plug in 190dp into the width if the phone's resolution is considered in the xxxhdpi bracket, and it'll plug in 170dp if it's not, since the regular `values` folder without any modifiers at the end is the default value.

So by making a change like this, you can finetune your layout to have it look similar across any type of screen across any type of device.

Also, there's no need for you to put your `RelativeLayout` inside of `ConstraintLayout`. You coded your `RelativeLayout` with the intentions to have it stretch completely inside the screen, which makes it serve no purpose inside `ConstraintLayout`.

It's like you're giving a Christmas present to a kid, but storing a box inside of a box. So the kid will have to unwrap the present twice before he gets the prize... which is inefficient.

Since your code is meant to work with RelativeLayout, you can get rid of the ConstraintLayout without interfering with your RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance
I did the tips that you said but did not work.

Comment: Please show some some images of what is the intended result and what is not working.

Comment: It is link of my app photo on galaxy s7  http://uupload.ir/files/sova_photo_in_galaxy_s7.jpg an it is on a7 http://uupload.ir/files/86cm_photo_on_galaxy_a7.jpg

Comment: Okay, with the two photos for comparison, I could see what your problem is. Your problem is actually more than just the hardcoding dp values that I mentioned in my answer. Not only do you hardcode values, but you're also laying out the Views improperly in your layout. For example, the `EditText` goes all the way off the screen in your s7 because you hardcoded the width to be 344dp, however that's way too long for the S7, so it's shown to be off the screen. What you want to do is to create a flexible layout, one that can fit across multiple screen sizes.

Comment: To do that, definitely AVOID setting a specific width or height value unless you need to. Instead, take advantage of using `wrap_content` and `match_parent`. Right now, you're using `RelativeLayout` improperly, thus causing your Buttons to overlap on top of each other due when there's insufficient space. This is because you're positioning your buttons primarily through hardcoded values through `margins` which makes it inflexible. Instead, you should take advantage of the features of your `RelativeLayout`, such as having `b8` be `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b7` to position it to the right.

Comment: But I should mention one last thing. The ideal Layout you want to achieve isn't easily achieved in `RelativeLayout` due to it's restrictions in positioning Views a certain way. So to combat this, you will most likely be nesting Layouts to achieve the look you want. But since it looks like you don't want to do this, I suggest you switch to using `ConstraintLayout` which does offer the flexibility to get the layout you want.